# Cannot see PHP Content Type in Eclipse preferences?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pdt

I have a new eclipse Juno installation with PDT. I imported my preferences and everything seems to be working normal except the in the content type section I do not see PHP Content Type. I see "%content-typ.name0"  for the php content type; as seen in the screen shot. What is wrong with it?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

? It is a bug of pdt.
"%content-type.name.0" is a variable name for a label, and the label consists in plugin.properties in eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.php.core_3.1.1.201209101312.jar
>content-type.name.0 = PHP Content Type

You can edit /META-INF/MANIFEST.MF in org.eclipse.php.core_3.1.1.201209101312.jar, insert "Bundle-Localization: plugin".(do not append it after blank line) And then start eclipse with -clean option.

Comment: I did add the line "Bundle-Localization: plugin" to the end of the file and still same problem. But I did not run it with -clean option. I have eclipse juno and I cannot run it from the command line. I am assuming this is the problem. How can I do this? thanks anyways

Comment: Open terminal, go to your eclipse installation folder, type "./eclipse -clean"(except quotation)...

Comment: I had made a plugin for fixing this issue. It is available here http://sourceforge.jp/downloads/users/1/1447/jp.sourceforge.pdt_tools.core.fragment_1.0.0.201209241055.jar Download it into eclipse/dropins folder. I'm not using it though.

Comment: That link is broken. I tried various variations, but no luck. Is it still available atlanto?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, but I deleted it since "you can edit" and the latest PDT 3.1.2 doesn't have this problem.